# Uninitialized Local Variable "name" Used

Tags: c++, variables, initialization, int, local

I keep getting this error in my code, uninitialized local variable "name" used. I set a variable like this

> int name = 0;

then later on in the code,

> int name = name + 1;

I am trying to set name to 0 then later on add 1 to it then go back to the beginning and still have it equaling name + 1. the problem is it keeps putting it back to 0.

To make it easier here is the part I am talking about.

```
int main()
{
    int w = 0;
    int choice;

    cout << "1: Register\n2: Login\nYour Choice:"; cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        string username, password;
        cout << "Select A Username: "; cin >> username;
        cout << "Select A Password: "; cin >> password;

        ofstream file;
        file.open("data\\" + username + ".txt");
        file << username << endl << password;
        file.close();

        main();
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        bool status = IsLoggedIn();

        if (!status)
        {
            int w = w + 1;
            cout << "Unsuccesfull Login!" << endl;
            system("PAUSE");

            if (w == 3)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (w == 2)
            {
                main();
            }
            else if (w == 1)
            {
                main();
            }
            else if (w == 0)
            {
                main();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Succesfully Logged In!" << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            return true;
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Well, you're trying to redeclare the same variable twice since you're including the type both times. Its not giving you the error I'd expect, but I would expect an error from this.

Comment: I am convinced both declarations are in a different scope. The code fails to compile with the error message `error: redeclaration of ‘int name’`.

Comment: @AlBundy the error is clear enough and it means the variable is declared twice in the same scope. Unless they post the full code I don't think we can help more..

Comment: @peval27: Check it out: goo.gl/5VKZj3. When it would be like you say then the error message is different. There is nothing regarding an uninitialized variable!

Comment: @AlBundy the code you posted there is `int main()
{
 int name = 0;
 
 int name = name + 1;
}` which is not correct. you are declaring the same variable twice.

Comment: Wow I am impressed with how many Suggestions there are in the first hour I just joined the website and I was expecting at least a day for the first one xD

Comment: @ActiveGaming try using keyword `static` before declaring the variable. Or you can declare the variable as a global variable (i.e. before main function). However, you should refactor this code into different methods.

Comment: @peval27 I searched up how to declare a global variable because I don't know how, and nothing said anything. So can you explain how.

Comment: @ActiveGaming just move `int w = 0;` before `int main()` if you need `w` as global variable.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was making a login system and i was making it so you could get the login wrong 3 times then it closes. that worked thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ complains when you try to declare two variables with the same name in the same scope.

Basically `int name;` creates the variable name. You can then address it by `name` without `int`.

You probably mean `int name = 0; [...] name = name + 1;`.

Comment: this stopped the error but now i need it to stay at name + 1 when i go back to int main()

Comment: @ActiveGaming I can't find any name in your program actually.

Comment: I was using name instead of the actual integer

Answer (score 2):

As you do not receive an error of redeclaring the variable `name` it seems like you use your `int name = name + 1;` somewhere in the code when it not see the first declaration. Here the problem is that `int name = name + 1;` second "name" is not declared before and you try to initialize your first "name" with it. 
From start is a a bad approach but here the problem is that when you declare `int name = name + 1;` it is not in the scope of `int name = 0`.

So first be sure you are incrementing your `name` in a place where the compiler "sees" the declaration of `int name = 0` and get rid of the type in `int name = name + 1;`

Comment: You are the first who got it! Up!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable twice. I'd suggest:

```
int name = 0;
```

then later on in the code,

```
name++;
```

You can use also: `++name;` or `name += 1`

Comment: I am convinced this is not correct! The c++ compiler complains when the same variable is declared again in the same scope.

Comment: `int name;` is a declaration of a varible. `int name = 0` is declaration and initialization. `name++` is an assignement, so that the value of name variable is incremented by 1.

Comment: Read what I wrote. Your answer does not solve OP problem because `name` is declared in two different scopes!

Comment: OP problem? where should we understand that's a question regarding OP? if `name` and `name` are meant to be two different variables, then they should use different names. If one is a member of a class, you can refer to `this.name` if you are inside the class, or `<objectName.name>` from outside, if `name` is a public member.

Comment: so later on in the code I should write name = name + 1; instead of int name = name + 1;

Comment: @ActiveGaming if `name` is the same variable, yes. You don't need to declare it twice.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get looks more like a warning.
Still it seems that you declared the same variable twice in the same scope and usualy in this case the error would be something like this: redeclaration of variable "name" of type int.

Maybe you declared "name" again in another scope and are trying to get the first one from another scope,which is impossible without pointers or refrences. This is just me guessing because you didn't post the whole code.